# How do I do routing for MySQL Read Replica?

Tags: mysql, rds

I have created 2 read replicas of my master mysql database on rds.

now all 3 have different connection endpoints.

1) does it mean that i have to manage random selection of these endpoints for my queries?

2) further to confirm, does it mean that I have to ensure that all my sql write queries needs to be routed to master endpoint

3) Is there any ways in which routing can be handled programmatically? ie db load balancing

Comment: you can also refer following - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes you have to manage it using some tool. read this - 
http://www.tecmint.com/install-haproxy-load-balancer-in-linux/2/

2) Yes , you have make sure that write's are redirected to master only. That can be done by defining seperate connection parameters to read and write with different hostnames.

3) Try HA PROXY its better way than handling it in code (ref link in point 1)

Comment: if read replicas are not sync instantly, then i have to also manage read queries of recently created record?

Comment: You need to redirect those reads to master only . More over you can use slaves for reports in case heavy transaction applications. Or you can use ndb/galera cluster as well which fits the bill nearby for transaction based system.